# Unable to upload file through asynctask android

Tags: android

hey guys i have got stuck in a problem i want to upload a file using ftp and i also uploads the through that but its shown a file size 0kb and the actual size of file is 1 mb if i call the upload method in my on click its work but it doesnot work with async task kindly help...

```
Button btn;
Runnable mUpdateUITimerTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {


    (new UpDateOperation()).execute("");

}

public void uploadFile(File fileName) {

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {

        client.connect(FTP_HOST, 21);
        client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);

        if (client.isAuthenticated() == true) {

            Log.d("hello", "world" + fileName.getName());
            client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);

            client.upload(fileName);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            client.disconnect(true);
            Log.d("chal", "ja");
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class UpDateOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



        uploadFile(null);
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

}

Comment: why are you calling uploadFile(null) with null param?

Comment: File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getPath() + "/map.jpg");
  

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

   
   uploadFile(f);

   return "hello";

Comment: ya actually i was calling the upload method in the wrong way

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the actuall file into the AsyncTask as a first parameter (like , or simply create it in your uploadFile method and pass the String with the file name